# Argparse and ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter. Formatting of default values when sys.stdin/stdout are selected as default

Tags: python, stdout, stdin, argparse

I am interested in using the ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter class formatter of argparse (my program has several sub-commands). By default, the input and output arguments are set to sys.stdin and sys.stdout respectively. However, the formatting for these two arguments may be a little bit confusing for users (e.g (default: ', mode 'r' at 0x10028e0c0>). Is there a way to specifically and easily change the output format for these two arguments to get something like 'default: STDIN' or 'default: STDOUT'?

Thank you

```
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG', 
                                 formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument('--infile',
                '-i',
                metavar='File',
                help='The input file/stream.',
                default=sys.stdin,
                type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                required=False)

parser.add_argument('--outfile',
                '-o',
                metavar='File',
                help='The output file/stream.',
                default=sys.stdout,
                type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                required=False)

parser.add_argument('--whatever-arg',
                '-w',
                type=str,
                default='any',
                help='Change something',
                required=False)


args = parser.parse_args()
parser.print_help()
```

Which gives:

```
usage: PROG [-h] [--infile File] [--outfile File]
            [--whatever-arg WHATEVER_ARG]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --infile File, -i File
                        The input file/stream. (default: <open file '<stdin>',
                        mode 'r' at 0x10028e0c0>)
  --outfile File, -o File
                        The output file/stream. (default: <open file
                        '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0x10028e150>)
  --whatever-arg WHATEVER_ARG, -w WHATEVER_ARG
                        Change something (default: any)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use the default formatter and explicitly list the defaults in the help?  Another option is to skip `FileType`, and open the files yourself later.  `FileType` is convenient for small scripts, not so good for big ones (where you need more control over when the files are open).

Comment: My program contains about 30 sub-programs all of them having there own set of arguments. Thus it is very convenient to use the formatting with default values. I can skip the FileType but in that case I won't benefit from argparse file check.

Comment: Then customizing the ` _get_help_string` method works.  That's all that this Default formatter class does anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can subclass ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter to do what you want.

```py
from argparse import ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,RawDescriptionHelpFormatter

class CustomFormatter(argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter, argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter):
    def _get_help_string(self, action):
        help = action.help
        if '%(default)' not in action.help:
            if action.default is not argparse.SUPPRESS:
                defaulting_nargs = [argparse.OPTIONAL, argparse.ZERO_OR_MORE]
                if action.option_strings or action.nargs in defaulting_nargs:
                    if type(action.default) == type(sys.stdin):
                        print action.default.name
                        help += ' (default: ' + str(action.default.name) + ')'
                    else:
                        help += ' (default: %(default)s)'
        return help

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG', formatter_class=CustomFormatter)
```

result for me is:

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --infile File, -i File
                        The input file/stream. (default: <stdin>)
  --outfile File, -o File
                        The output file/stream. (default: <stdout>)
  --whatever-arg WHATEVER_ARG, -w WHATEVER_ARG
                        Change something (default: any)
```

Comment: Indent after the `def` is off.  Otherwise the concept is valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you give `default='-'` instead of `sys.stdin`, the help display would be

```
the input file/stream. (default: -)
```

That is, help shows the default string, but `FileType` converts `'-'` to stdin/out.

As `A.H` shows you can customize the `_get_help_string` method.  It doesn't matter which class you inherit from, since modifying that method is all that ADHF does:

```
class ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter(HelpFormatter):
    """...
    """
    def _get_help_string(self, action):
        help = action.help
        if '%(default)' not in action.help:
            if action.default is not SUPPRESS:
                defaulting_nargs = [OPTIONAL, ZERO_OR_MORE]
                if action.option_strings or action.nargs in defaulting_nargs:
                    help += ' (default: %(default)s)'
        return help
```

And note that all this modification does is add a string to the `help` parameter - just the `(default: %(default)s)`

That means you could get a similar effect by adjusting your own `help` lines, e.g.

```
parser.add_argument('--infile',
                '-i',
                metavar='File',
                help='The input file/stream, (default: stdin).',
                default='-',
                type=argparse.FileType('r'))

parser.add_argument('--whatever-arg',
                '-w',
                default='any',
                help='Change something, (default: %(default)s)')
```

In other words it saves you typing `(default: %(default)s)` for 28 of your arguments.

If you are uncomfortable customizing the HelpFormatter class (though that is what developers recommend - with suitable cautions), you could tweak your own setup.  For example, make simple helper function that adds the extra string to each help line:

```
def foohelp(astr):
    return astr + ' (default: %(default)s)'

arg1 = parser.add_argument('-f','--fooarg', help=foohelp('help string'))
```

Speaking of changing the setup programmatically, it's worth noting that `add_argument` creates an `Action` object. You can save a link to that, as I did here, and tweak parameters.

```
arg1 = parser.add_argument('-f','--fooarg', help='help string')
print arg1.help
arg1.help = foohelp(arg1.help)  # modify help after creation
print arg1.help
```

With 30 arguments you probably have done a lot of copy-n-paste to define them, or writen various helper functions to streamline the setup.  Adding the default display is just another of those tasks.  You can do it during setup, or you can do it via a custom Formatter.

Comment: These are also very nice solutions. Thanks a lot for your help.